# Restrict date to financial year only - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `DateTimeField` to get data control. Here I want user to select date in financial year only:
ex: 
Today date: 11 March 2020 
so this case user can select from `1 April 2019` to till date.

I tried it but failed I able to restrict for last one year.
like for above example user can select from 11 March 2019 to till date.

```
DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1, DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day)
```

My `onShowPicker` looks like:

```
onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
          return showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1, DateTime.now().month,
                DateTime.now().day),
            initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
            lastDate: DateTime.now(),
          );
        },
```

Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var minus = 0;
if (now.month <= 3) {
  minus = 1;
}
var firstDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year - minus, 4, 1);
```

and

```
firstDate: firstDate,
```